# How to convert file ogg to wav in C#

Tags: c#, audio, codec

When I use [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC)  to record audio. On Chrome I get wav file, on firefox I get ogg file. So I want to know how to convert ogg to wav in C#?

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can make use of the [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) library to convert between formats

Comment: you'd need to use something NVorbis as well, since NAudio does not come with built-in ogg support: https://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/235249

Comment: NAudio is now here: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio

Answer (score -1):

[How to convert to wav in C#](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,articles.aspx#how-to-convert-to-wav)

```
    static void ToWav()
    {
        string fileName = @"e:\down\male.ogg";
        using (DsReader dr = new DsReader(fileName))
        {
            if (dr.HasAudio)
            {
                IntPtr format = dr.ReadFormat();
                using (WaveWriter ww = new WaveWriter(File.Create(fileName + ".wav"),
                    AudioCompressionManager.FormatBytes(format)))
                {
                    byte[] data = dr.ReadData();
                    ww.WriteData(data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is DsReader?